# python Socket send ascii command and receive response

Tags: sockets, python-3.x

I am trying to establish connection to a ADAM-4017+ I/O module over the network using a Lantronix EDS2100 module through socket communication in python.  For the life of me I cannot get it to work.

The EDS has an IP address and a port (10001) that the adam unit is connected to.  I am trying to query the adam for the value of ch 1 (ascii command is #000)

Any help greatly appreciated:

```
import socket
edsIP = "192.168.1.135"
edsPORT = 10001
MESSAGE="#000\r"


srvsock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
srvsock.bind( ('',23000))
srvsock.listen(1)
newsock, (remhost, remport) = srvsock.accept()
srvsock.send((MESSAGE),(edsIP, EdsPORT) )



 while 1:


    data, addr = srvsock.recv(4096) 
    print ("received message:", data,addr)
    srvsock.close()
```

Comment: Is the workflow supposed to be that you listen for a connection from the unit, as opposed to connecting to it? From what I see, you bind a port and wait for connections.

Comment: workflow is as follows:  send ascii command and then receive response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about this device specifically, but from your description, you said its expecting a connection on port 10001. But what you are doing in your code is opening your own socket and listening for connections on port 23000, and then waiting for connections. If you aren't expecting something to connect to you, then you will just be waiting for no reason.

If all your device needs is for you to connect and send a message, then I would think this would do it:

```py
import socket

edsIP = "192.168.1.135"
edsPORT = 10001
MESSAGE="#000\r"

srvsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
srvsock.settimeout(3) # 3 second timeout on commands
srvsock.connect((edsIP, edsPORT)))
srvsock.sendall(MESSAGE)

data = srvsock.recv(4096) 
print "received message:", data

srvsock.close()
```

**Update**

Your comments suggest you might be using python3. If so, you may have to adjust the code like this:

```
MESSAGE=b'#000\r'
```

And when you receive your `bytes` response, if you want to turn it into a string:

```
print data.decode("UTF-8")
```

Comment: I tried this adding parantheses around the print and removing extra bracket on the connect line.  It returns:    srvsock.send(MESSAGE)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: fyi I am a NOOB python programmer

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3 and APtna studio PyDev

Comment: Yea figured. See my update. You need to send a bytes object instead of a string

Comment: Now the console just hangs.  So it seams that the script is working but no response is be returned.  I used the \r as the 'carriage return'  for entering the command. Is that needed?

Comment: No you should probably only be sending the command your device expects. You don't have to simulate any kind of carriage return

Comment: Does receive give me the response in binary?  How do I turn that into a str?  also it seams to only sometimes get the response?  response looks like b'xff'

Comment: Ya it returns a bytes object as well. See another update on decoding it to unicode

Answer (score 0):

The only problem i can see directly is that you have indented the while statement with one space, but thats probably just from cutting and pasting in here.

After some testing It's clear that when you try to accept on the serversocket it will block, so you're never sending anything to your device.